# Collapsing all inner braces in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, block, shortcut, braces, code-folding

Suppose we have something like this:

```
{                      // 1
    A();
    {                  // 1.1
        B();
        {              // 1.1.1
            {          // 1.1.1.1
                D();
            }
            X();
            {          // 1.1.1.2
                E();
            }
        }
        C();
        {              // 1.1.2
            F();
        }
    }
}
```

And we'd like to collapse block `1.1.1` along with all the blocks in it to get:

```
{                      // 1
    A();
    {                  // 1.1
        B();
        {...}          // 1.1.1
        //  {...}         1.1.1.1 also collapsed in 1.1.1
        //  X();
        //  {...}         1.1.1.2 also collapsed in 1.1.2
        C();
        {              // 1.1.2
            F();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it quickly (esp. in case of multiple layers of sub-blocks)?

I know of CTRL+M+L, which I tend to use quite often, and would love to learn more.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feauture I was looking for was in **Edit.Outlining.Collapse All in:**

It seems to not have a shortcut assigned by default, so

1. I went to **Tools.Options...**
2. Then in the left panel select **Environment > Keyboard**
3. Find **Edit.CollapseAllincurrentblock** on the right
4. In editbox "Press shortcut keys", pressed **CTRL+M, CTRL+B** in order
5. In "Use new shortcut in:", I used **Global**
6. Click **Assign**
7. Done.

Now, if you're in a block, clicking CTRL+M followed by CTRL+B should collapse all blocks in current block. The only missing part is that the current block itself remains expanded, but that can be fixed with CTRL+M, CTRL+S (collapse current region, which collapses the current block, but not inner blocks).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 and can not find the Edit.CollapseAllInCurrentBlock command in the settings. Am I missing something?